# what is ^ in Clojure when define a function?

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and I've been messed up with ^ in Clojure
I'm currently reading clojure code of Jepsen which is used to test the consistency of distributed database.

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/jepsen-io/mongodb/blob/master/src/jepsen/mongodb/mongo.clj).
In row 50 there is a *^MongoDatabase*. Or:

```
(defn ^MongoCollection collection
"Gets a Mongo collection from a DB."
[^MongoDatabase db collection-name]
(.getCollection db collection-name))
```

I have no idea what it is because `^MongoDatabase` or `MongoCollection` is never used in this function.

Can anyone give me some help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, that's a *type hint* saying `collection` should return a `MongoCollection` instance and `db` arg should be a `MongoDatabase` instance. This is useful for performance reasons, to avoid unnecessary reflection.

See [this guide](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#__code_code_and_code_code_metadata) for more.

> Another use of `^` is for type hints. These are used to tell the compiler what type the value will be and allow it to perform type specific optimizations thus potentially making resultant code faster:

Comment: Awesome, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The cap symbol `^` is used in Clojure for two purposes.

The first one is for type hints. When declaring a function, you may mark arguments' types or the result value as follows:

```
(defn ^String concat-strings
  [^String a ^String b]
  (str a b))
```

Type hints help the compiler to perform some optimizations.

The second option of using cap is when declaring metadata. The metadata might be either a boolean flag or a map. For example:

```
(def ^:private secret "test")
```

Now the variable above is marked as private so it won't be available from other namespaces.

Here is a meta-map usage example:

```
(def ^{:private true
       :doc "My super secret password"
       :added "product-version"}
   secret
   "test")
```

Let's try to read the metadata for that variable:

```
(meta #'secret)
```

returns

```
{:private true,
 :doc "My super secret password",
 :added "product-version",
 :line 70,
 :column 7,
 :file "*cider-repl localhost*",
 :name secret,
 :ns #namespace[user]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another point to beware of is that type hints can be deceptive (i.e. they have no "enforcement" or "warning" utility):

```
(defn foo [x]
  (type x))

(defn bar [^String x]
  (type x))

(foo "abc") => java.lang.String
(foo 123)   => java.lang.Long

(bar "abc") => java.lang.String
(bar 123)   => java.lang.Long
```

In general, I would avoid type hints as they are rarely necessary (unless dealing with low-level Java code).